# How to string-concatenate multiple string columns in pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to concatenate two rows in a DataFrame into one row. My current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['string1', 'string2'])
df.loc[len(df), :] = ['Hello', 'This is Sam']
df.loc[len(df), :] = ['how are you?', 'from Canada']

#create the next row: ['Hello how are you?', 'This is Sam from Canada']
```

How to do it?

You can test the code [here](https://repl.it/@Chan2019/MurkyRingedExternalcommand).

Comment: Hi, please post some example data and what the result should look like

Comment: You asked ***"How to concatenate rows..."*** but you really meant ***"How to string-concatenate multiple text columns...?"*** Since you want to string-concatenate `string1` column between rows 1 and 2, e.g. 'This is Sam' + 'from Canada'. That's concatenating columns not rows, and it's string-concatenation (multiple strings into one string, not the usual concatenating multiple rows into one dataframe containing multiple rows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `agg` with `append`:

```
df = df.append(df.agg(' '.join), ignore_index=True)
df

              string1                  string2
0               Hello              This is Sam
1        how are you?              from Canada
2  Hello how are you?  This is Sam from Canada
```